# What scope does an "Everyone" principal have in Amazon SQS permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

When specifying permissions on an Amazon AWS SQS queue you can specify a principal or say `Everyone`. What does `Everyone` mean? This is not explicitly document anywhere I could find.

Does this mean "anyone in my AWS account" or "the whole world including evil hackers"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone means everyone, with or without an AWS account - so unless you want to be on the hook for potential abuse, probably not a good idea unless you restricted with appropriate conditions, i.e. by IP Address.